# Compare two objects and find the matched objects from the array using react

Tags: javascript

First Object :

```
{
  first: 'value',
  second: 'value',
  third: 'value',
  four: 'value',
};
```

Second Object

```
{
  id: 'value',
  schema: 'value',
  definitions: {
    TypeVal: {
      properties: {
        First: { description: '...', title: 'test first' },
      },
      Type: {
        third: { description: '...', title: 'test third' },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I try to compare my first and second objects and need to get the first object keys with the second object key. If the key contains in the second object need to get the entire object.

In the first object, I have first, second, third, and four key values. In the second object I have only First and third. I need to get them both first and third objects from the second object.

I tried the below code to compare both objects and try to get the matched key

```
Object.keys(FirstObject).map((key) => {
  objFinal[key] = FirstObject[key];
  var result1 = SecondObject.filter((e) => e.key === key);
  console.log('result1', result1);
});
```

Need  below object data in result :

first (first object equals with second object ) : `First: {description: "...",  title: "test first"}`

third (first object equals with second object ) `third: {description: "...",  title: "test third"}`